# UI Hang while replacing fragment from setOnInfoWindowClickListener interface method of Google Map

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

I am using google map in my application and display markers.

Now on click of marker window I want to replace the current fragment with other fragment.

```
for (StoreData store : comp.getArrStoreList()) {
                LatLng l = new LatLng(Double.parseDouble(store.getLat()),
                        Double.parseDouble(store.getLng()));

                MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(l)
                        .title(store.getName())
                        .snippet(store.getCity())
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                                .defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE));

                Marker mrkr = mapCompanyList.addMarker(marker);

                CompanyStoreData companyStoreData = new CompanyStoreData();

                companyStoreData.setStoreData(store);

                companyStoreData.setCompanyId(comp.getId());

                listStoreData.put(mrkr, companyStoreData);


                mapCompanyList
                .setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                        try {

                            StoreDetailsFragment storeDetails = new StoreDetailsFragment();
                            Bundle b = new Bundle();

                            b.putSerializable(UserDefaults.STORE_OBJECT,
                                    listStoreData.get(marker).getStoreData());
                            b.putString("StoreAppID", listStoreData.get(marker).getCompanyId());

                            storeDetails.setArguments(b);

                            ((BaseTabbarContainer) companyListFragment.getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(
                                    storeDetails, true); // here my UI is hang

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", "Exception :: " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
            }
```

I am creating one hashmap which has `<marker,storedata>`  marker as a key and storedata (my custom class object) as a value.

on onInfoWindowClick I am getting instance of store data on basis of key of hashmap(). It is  working well but

```
((BaseTabbarContainer) companyListFragment.getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(
                                        storeDetails, true);
```

Here my UI is getting hang. What is the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the issue . if any one facing this issue please refer this.

What I done is create one handler to run the code snippet after some delay and **return** from the `onInfoWindowClick` method after calling handler.

```
mapCompanyList
                .setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {

                        final Marker mark = marker;
                        try {

                            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    callStore(mark);
                                }
                            }, 100);


                            return;
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e("Exception", "Exception :: " + e.getMessage());
                        }

                    }
                });
```

**callStore**

```
    private void callStore(Marker marker) {
        StoreDetailsFragment storeDetails = new StoreDetailsFragment();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putSerializable(UserDefaults.STORE_OBJECT,
                listStoreData.get(marker).getStoreData());
        b.putString("StoreAppID", listStoreData.get(marker).getCompanyId());

        storeDetails.setArguments(b);

        ((BaseTabbarContainer) CompanyListFragment.this.getParentFragment()).replaceFragment(
                storeDetails, true);

    }
```

and It worked;

**But I still don't get why it is getting hang though and why it is resolved after returning from  onInfoWindowClick method while running code in post delay?if any one have any idea please share.**

Comment: I actually have the same issue and also got it to work with a timer. But I don't think it's a good fix, because it doesn't guarantee that this works. Very unfortunate. I'd also like to hear if someone else has an idea why this is happening exactly.

Comment: I know it is not a good fix though it is working. That is why I have also mentioned to share any good way to fix this issue in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

I was also facing this problem, for me I solved by stop using `fragmentManager.executePendingTransactions()`, if I use this line to replace fragment then its just HANG, but without this line its working without any problem. hope it will help for someone who will face similar problem. thanks.