# How to Call Navigation Drawer Fragment From A Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2

So I have a Google Map integrated in one of my Fragment components and I also have a navigation drawer. The google maps is in one of my drawer fragments. My question is how do I change fragments when I click a place marker info window.

```
public class AboutFragment extends Fragment {
   private GoogleMap mMap;
```

...

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Clicked on Info view", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            // This is where I want to call my ProductsFragment class.


        }
});
```

...

```
}
```

This is what my ProductsFragment class looks like below.

```
public class ProductsFragment extends Fragment {


public ProductsFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_products, container, false);
}
```

}

I tried using FragmentManager but I got errors. Maybe I wasnt doing it right but can you guys help me?

Thanks

Comment: What error you got with FragmentManager? Check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/22986798/1384010 if you have faced same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work

```
Fragment fragment = fragmentProducts;
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment aboutFragment = MainActivity.setFragment();
ft.remove(aboutFragment);
ft.add(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
```

But it doesnt change the ActionBar title?

Any clues to how to go changing that in this class?

Answer (score 0):

> *"But it doesnt change the ActionBar title? Any clues to how to go
>   changing that in this class?"*

**yeah just call:**

```
getActionBar().setTtitle(fragmentTitle);
```

**where ?**

** you can add listener :) to drawer

```
DrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(DrawerLayout.DrawerListener)

// example for open/close/changeState etc
@Override
public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            // set title or subtitle
            getActionBar().setSubtitle(title);
}
```

**or in onBackPressed() if u get back from prev fragment

**or after ItemSelected from fragment adapter

**or after statement as in yr code:

```
ft.add(R.id.container_body, fragment).commit();
```

**or in fragment

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // set title or subtitle
    getActionBar().setSubtitle(fragmentTitle);
}
```

> **as you see it depends where & when u wanna do it**
>
> *I get the error "cannot resolve method getActionBar()". Do I need something else with that line of code?*

[ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

[AppCompatActivity](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.htmlhttp://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html?m=1)

Comment: I get the error "cannot resolve method getActionBar()". Do I need something else with that line of code?